# Creating signature in Java with existing public key for JWT

Tags: java, jwt, box-api, signature, box

I need your help once again...

I want to access the Box API and authorize using a JWT (Json Web Token). To do so, I need to create a Assertion:
*"Every JWT assertion is composed of three components, the header, the claims, and the signature.

 - The header specifies the algorithm used for the JWT signature.

 - The claims contain the information necessary to authenticate and provide the correct token.

 - The signature is used to verify the identify of the application and is verified using the public key.


Once encoded and concatenated, the JWT assertion will look like this:
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJpc3MiOiJ2Z3.
B2bWFvaDJjZ2ZjNGRuMzFnMWx0cmlhbmdlZCIsInN1YiI.
6IjE2ODczOTQzIiwiZXhwIjoxNDI5MDM3ODYwLCJqdGkiOiJ"*

So, an RSA Keypair I had to create before and had to deposit the public key in the Box devolper application.

Now, I don't know how to create the signature.
I found a solution with creating the Keypair, but since I already have this, I don't know how to modify the code.

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Signature;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

    byte[] data = "test".getBytes("UTF8");

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
    sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
    sig.update(data);
    byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
    System.out.println("Singature:" + new  
           BASE64Encoder().encode(signatureBytes));

    sig.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
    sig.update(data);

    System.out.println(sig.verify(signatureBytes));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the official [Java SDK for Box](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk)? It will handle the JWT authentication flow for you. If you want to write it yourself, you might check out their [JWT implementation](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/box/sdk/BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java) for inspiration.

Comment: Once you've generated your Key Pair, to need to store it somehow. One PEM-file for the public key and one for the private key is a common way to store it. However, when I tried to setup code similar to yours a few weeks ago, I ended up switching from MD5 with RSA to HMAC-SHA256 because the process of reading a PEM file to a Java KeyPari was so tedious and included so many libraries!

Answer (score 5):

Box Api says

> RSA keypair must be in PEM format

So, you need to export your public key to PEM. Use this code (java8)

```
 public static String exportPublicKeyAsPem(PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    sw.write("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
    sw.write(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
    sw.write("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");

    return sw.toString();
 }
```

Creating a signed JWT token can be done in this way (You can also use a library)

```
public static String signJWT (String header, String payload, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception{
    String token = 
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(header.getBytes())
            + "."
            +Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(payload.getBytes());

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    sig.initSign(privateKey);
    sig.update(token.getBytes());
    byte[] signature = sig.sign();

    return token + "." + Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
}
```

Using the code:

```
public final static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{

    String header = "{\"alg\": \"RS256\",\"typ\": \"JWT\"}";
    String payload = "{\"sub\": \"1234567890\",\"name\": \"John Doe\"}";

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

    String publicKeyPem = exportPublicKeyAsPem(keyPair.getPublic());
    String signedToken = signJWT (header, payload, keyPair.getPrivate());

    System.out.println(publicKeyPem);
    System.out.println(signedToken);
}
```

Finally you will need to store the key pair and load before using it. I recommend you to pregenerate the keypair using openssl as [BoxApi documentation says](https://docs.box.com/docs/app-auth)